# Yang Mills Hamiltonian: why do we use the Weyl's temporal gauge?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, hamiltonian, yang-mills, gauge

Do you know why in the quantization of $SU(2)$ Yang-Mills Gauge Theory, it is always chosen the Weyl (temporal) gauge to derive the Hamiltonian?

Is it possible to fix another gauge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formally, the gauge-invariant observables do not depend on the choice of gauge-fixing condition (such as, e.g., Lorenz gauge, Coulomb gauge, axial gauge, temporal gauge, etc). Similarly, the Hamiltonian can formally be gauge-fixed in any gauge.

However, it is my understanding that to avoid the [Gribov problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gribov_ambiguity), an algebraic (rather than a differential) gauge-fixing condition is preferred. See also the footnote on p. 15 in S. Weinberg, *Quantum Theory of Fields,* Vol 2.

Comment: Well, Weinberg only argues in favor of the axial gauge and does not mention the Weyl gauge. The Gribov ambiguities only appear for the Coulomb gauge and thus this does not explain why one favors the Weyl gauge over, say, the axial gauge.